# Does my ER diagram properly represent a basic website?

Tags: database, entity-relationship, erd

I'm trying to model a website in an ER-Diagram.

- The users of the website have a unique user name. Their registration date is also saved, as is their email address and date of birth.
- Users can write posts which consist of an image and a description. A user can write any number of posts, but one post is created by exactly one user.
- Posts are sorted into categories with unique titles. Each post can be assigned to any number of categories, but at least one.
- In order to be able to give feedback on the posts, users have the option to rate a post. A rating is uniquely identified by an artificial ID, consists of a given number of stars (e.g. 3 out of 5) and can contain a comment.

For the participation constraints, I'm using [min, max]-notation.

Here is what I've been able to come with up:

[image: My ER-Diagram]

1. Did I get the participation constraints right?
2. I'm not sure if post is a weak entity. A post can only exist if a user writes it, yes? The same would apply to "Rating" though. However, in the task it only specifics that Rating has a unique key, not sure about post.